# ASp.NET 4.5 How to find specific error term for Try Catch of an error ex.message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

I want to trap a missing value from my grid and make it a default value to pass to another procedure.
I know the ex.message is "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."
but unlike the old Err.xxx you could get both its description and Number by this for example:
      Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3021
            'do something

so how do I know what I am "Catching" based on the ex.Message? there is no ex.ErrorNumber or Phrase

```
Try

Session("gblStoreID") = selectedRow.Cells(4).Text' < Error happens here since there is no column 4, some times...

Catch ex As **What_Goes_Here**
      'So I want to just make the session var 5 
Session("gblStoreID") = 5

    Catch ex As Exception
    debug.print ex.Message
End Try
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: well yes is that what I need? and how do you find these? I just tried it now, and that's not what it is, I still went down the  Catch ex As Exception. But I need to find out how to get want it wants. Is there a way to print out something in debug mode? to get the exact value it wants.

Comment: When you encounter a server error, it tells you what kind of error it is.  In my screenshot, I created an array with 4 items, and tried to access a non-existing 5th item.  Same idea that you have.

http://i.imgur.com/Nx5Wyfn.png

Comment: Sweet... I had to get rid of the try catch then ran it an got this > ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I just tried it and it WORKED SWEET !!!!!!!!  So how do you give comment recognition?

Comment: No idea. :)  Glad it helped.